# How to access RefreshIndicatorState of RefreshIndicator?

Tags: widget, material-design, flutter

The docs for [`RefreshIndicator`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) suggest you can programmatically trigger the refresh behaviour via the [`RefreshIndicatorState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicatorState-class.html) class.

How do I access an instance of this class, assuming I've added a `RefreshIndicator` widget to my application? I can't see a property to access it and I'm assuming `createState()` is only used by the Flutter framework.

To avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I should explain my reason for doing this is to perform a visually pleasing refresh of my list when my user first opens the app. The list will be empty initially and the refresh will poll my server for data.

Comment: In typical fashion, I seem to have found the answer moments after posting. This code looks promising: https://github.com/ics042/flutter_examples/blob/89f3b494bafbe7d170667147f448473b6a27916b/lib/basic/overscroll_http.dart#L16. Will write up an answer if it works (and no-one else does).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change state of Flutter widget from outside it's State class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485375/change-state-of-flutter-widget-from-outside-its-state-class)

Comment: See also this example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/overscroll_demo.dart

Answer (score 8):

See https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicatorState/show.html and a [usage example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f408bb06f9361793ca85493c38d809ee1e2f7e30/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/overscroll_demo.dart#L54) in the Flutter Gallery

Essentially

```
var indicator = new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
```

and then

```
indicator.currentState.show();
```

after it's built.